# Cursor at the end on a editable div Angular 6

Tags: html, cursor, angular6, contenteditable

I'm having this problem:

I'm starting with Angular 6, so I wanted to do a text editor which shows the css styles while you are typing. 
Seeing that I wasn't able to show the Css styles inside of Textareas, I tried with an editable div when I show the text on `[innerHTML]=""`.
The main problem is when I call the method bound to an (input), the cursor goes to the start of the div, instead of go to the last position to keep typing.

I'm using the following div:

```
<div class="derecha" id="editable" [innerHTML]="textoCompleto" contenteditable="true" (input)="aTexto($event.target.innerText)"></div>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you please add the details of `textoCompleto` and inside of `aTexto()` method in your question? @adelafuentep

Comment: It just returns the same text it sends but with <b> tags in some words